# How to show uploading progress bar while uploading data to server?

Tags: android, progress-bar, uploading

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

httpClient.execute(request);
```

I use this code to upload the data to server in post , Now i want to show uploading progress bar , So please any body can help me,,

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](http://delimitry.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-upload-progress.html) link. 
You should use URLHttpConnection. Apache HTTP Client is deprecated and removed from newest 6.0 Android.

Comment: Thanks, Here in this code File is uploading,But i need to upload other user info data like name,email,  etc how to add that with the url